# jQuery Isotope loading issue

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-isotope, pageload

I am actually trying to build a image gallery with jquery Isotope.
I dont know why, but sometimes the gallery works perfectly and sometimes it has some kind of loading issue as you can see in my screenshot.

Source: www.sarahraaber.com

[image]

I already added a timer on pageload and the document loaded function to the head of my .js file. :-/
Any ideas how to work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before when using Isotope, it is usually a JS timing issue. Can you add a setTimeout() with a long timer of say 2000 within the initialisation or callback functions, then test to see if it still happens? That should help confirm.

I have also noticed on your site that resizing the browser clears up the layout issues. Try calling the Isotope update function once all has loaded to correctly update the layout.

Comment: I tried it with $(window).load with the result that the hole isotope stopped working. U're right that the issue is solved after resizing the window, I will give it a try with a longer timeout

EDIT: After setting the timeout to 5000 nearly all images where corretly loaded, but anyway, that realy couldnt be the solution for that :P
Maybe i should add a pager to the gallery to get it faster loaded.

Comment: 1: Add the  `.imagesLoaded()` function around the `.isotope()` initialisation, this allows all images to load before the layout is updated. 2: When you initialise the plugin you can add a callback function that "should" get run once the layout is ready, you could call the update method in that. E.g. `$container.isotope(options, function(){ $container.isotope( 'reLayout', }) );` - it is a little crude but may solve your issue.

Comment: The first one sounds good, gonna try this tomorrow and will report after, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hmm that is strange, now it works, but never on the first pageload. When i clear the cache the isotope wont take effect on first load. One time F5 and tadaa ... -.-"

Comment: Again, sounds like timing. Try loading the isotope.js file first in the DOM (just after jQuery if possible) so it is fully loaded and available when your `.isotope()` initialization javascript is run.

Comment: Oh n1, that seems like to do the trick :D
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have never used jquery isotope, but it looks like it does the same as jquery masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/). Masonry has a drupal views plugin :http://drupal.org/project/masonry .  You might have more luck with the Masonry module.

Comment: If the masonry module did not work you might want to consider posting in the issue queue.

Comment: I'll give it another try, if it fails again, I am going to post it, but anyway the isotope plugin should work aswell :-/

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late, but in my case there was a much simpler solution:

my isotope elements had no fixed height and because of that the javascript was executed before all the images were loaded and because of that, the elements had not the right height!

after adding:

```
.isotope-item{
  height:300px;  
}
```

the code was able to calculate the positions of the items, even before the images were loaded!